# Using ArrayList<Book> to store book titles

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on a homework assignment and have not been able to figure out what I've done wrong.

I am trying to create a list of book titles using ArrayList

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.awt.print.Book;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Books {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        ArrayList<Book> bookTitle = new ArrayList<Book>();


        bookTitle.add ("Book title 1");
        bookTitle.add ("Book title 2");
        bookTitle.add ("Book title 3");

        System.out.println("Size of Book list: " + bookTitle.size());

    }

}
```

This code gives me the following error on the three bookTitle.add lines:
"The Method add(Book) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

So then I tried this:

```
Book book1 = new Book("Book title");
        bookTitle.add (book1);
```

This gave me a "The constructor Book(String) is undefined" error.

Please keep in mind I'm a noob at Java so I'm probably doing some very basic error and not realizing it.

I greatly appreciate your help and time.

Comment: Do you really think this class does what you want? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/Book.html

Comment: You'll need to write your own `Book` class, instead of using the one that Java provides at `java.awt.print.Book`.  If you put your own `Book.java` in the same directory as `Books.java`, and remove the first `import` line from `Books.java`, you will start to make some progress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Method add(Book) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (String).**

This is because, as you can see that generics type in your `ArrayList<Book> bookTitle = new ArrayList<Book>();`
is `Book` but you add `String` value in bookTitle, `bookTitle.add ("Book title 1");`

Try `ArrayList<String> bookTitle = new ArrayList<String>();`

If you still want to use `Book` not `String`, then create a `Book` class eg:

```
public class Book{
private String bookName;

public Book(){}

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }
}
```

then in your main method try :

```
Book book1 = new Book();
book1.setBookName("Book title 1");

ArrayList<Book> bookTitle = new ArrayList<Book>();
bookTitle.add (book1);

 for(Book b :bookTitle){
            System.out.println(b.getBookName());
        }
```

Note: Remove the `import java.awt.print.Book;`

Comment: I think this is the right answer.  java.awt.Book is a built-in class that, while it roughly represents a book, it's not what you want, and because it's built-in, adding a new constructor won't help.

Answer (score 2):

> The constructor Book(String) is undefined

You have to define a constructor in your class Book that takes a String as a parameter.

For example:

```
class Book{

private String bookName;

public Book(String bookName){
 this.bookName=bookName;
}

}
```

**UPDATE**

And after @Josh comments realize that you are importing import `java.awt.print.Book;` . You sure want to import your own `Book` implementation, so delete that line and import the correct one!!

Comment: The `Book` class has to be [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/Book.html) judging from the imports.